# Conan failed install package

Tags: c++, conan

Since the last conan (1.23.0) I can't install some package for example I want to install 
[mysql-connectorc](https://bintray.com/bincrafters/public-conan/mysql-connector-c%3Abincrafters/6.1.11%3Astable)

> mysql-connector-c/6.1.11@bincrafters/stable

But I got this error:

```
ERROR: Failed requirement 'OpenSSL/1.0.2s@conan/stable' from 'mysql-connector-c/6.1.11@bincrafters/stable'
ERROR: Requested 'OpenSSL/1.0.2s@conan/stable' but found case incompatible 'openssl'
Case insensitive filesystem can't manage this
CMake Error at Build/conan.cmake:402 (message):
  Conan install failed='1'
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  Build/conan.cmake:492 (conan_cmake_install)
  Alpaga/Alpaga.cmake:23 (conan_cmake_run)
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (include)
```

Alpaga.cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(Alpaga)

#################
#   USE C++17   #
#################
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED 17 ON)

#############
#   CONAN   #
#############
if(NOT EXISTS "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake")
   message(STATUS "Downloading conan.cmake from https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan")
   file(DOWNLOAD "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/conan-io/cmake-conan/master/conan.cmake"
                  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake")
endif()
include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake)

#####################
#   CONAN PACKAGE   #
#####################
conan_cmake_run(REQUIRES
    mysql-connector-c/6.1.11@bincrafters/stable

#   boost/1.71.0@conan/stable
    BASIC_SETUP
    BUILD missing
)
```

I don't know how patch this new error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When installing a package which is already installed, but using a different case, will result on your error:

> ERROR: Requested 'OpenSSL/1.0.2s@conan/stable' but found case incompatible 'openssl'

Case insensitive filesystem can not manage this. The package `openssl` is already installed. To solve this problem the different package with the same name must be removed:

```
$ conan remove "openssl/*"
```

Anyway, [mysql-connector-c/6.1.11@bincrafters/stable](https://github.com/bincrafters/conan-mysql-connector-c) is totally deprecated and you must use [mysql-connector-c/6.1.11@](https://conan.io/center/mysql-connector-c/6.1.11) instead:

```
$ conan install mysql-connector-c/6.1.11@ -r conan-center
```

Of course, you need to update the requirement reference in your cmake file too.